# как отобразить контекстно-зависимую справку?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Наверно вопрос в названии темы неверен, но надо сделать вот как:
есть вью кнопки Help, в клике которой эмулируется нажатие Help-"?" кнопки

```
private void cmdHelp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
//найти форму
var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)sender);
 while (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) != null)
  {
    parent=VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
  } ;
 IntPtr windowHandle = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper((Window)parent).Handle;
        SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_CONTEXTHELP, IntPtr.Zero);
// и что делать дальше?
}
```

Вот тут https://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/easy-help-with-wpf/ научился как сделать вызов самой контекстно-зависимой справки.
А теперь хочется скрестить кнопку (когда на неё нажали, подвели курсор со знаком вопроса к контролу и ещё раз кликнули) и вот тогда бы показалась та самая справка, кот появляется на нажатие F1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Боюсь, вы идёте по тупиковой ветке.

Отсылка команды `SC_CONTEXTHELP` действительно показывает курсор со знаком вопроса, по после этого по клику контрол, на котором был произведён клик, получает сообщение `WM_HELP`. Но в WPF всё окно — один контрол, так что вам просто некуда прицепить обработчик `WM_HELP`.

Я бы сделал не так. Я бы по клику на кнопку контекстной справки вывел над все приложением прозрачный фрейм, глотающий клики. По нажатию Esc его нужно, понятно, убрать. По клику вы запоминаете координаты, убираете фрейм, при помощи [`VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms608753%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) определяете элемент, по котором был произведён клик, а дальше повторяете логику функции `Executed` из процитированной вами статьи для `parent`, равного найденному элементу.

---

Закодировал готовый пример, вот.

Класс `Help` из примера укоротил. Убрал файл с хелпом для простоты, и вынес реализацию команды в главное окно, где ему и место:

```
public static class Help
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty KeywordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Keyword", typeof(string), typeof(Help));

    public static string GetKeyword(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (string)d.GetValue(KeywordProperty);
    }

    public static void SetKeyword(DependencyObject d, string value)
    {
        d.SetValue(KeywordProperty, value);
    }

    public static string FindKeyword(DependencyObject o)
    {
        // зачем тут была нужна рекурсия, ума не приложу
        while (o != null)
        {
            string keyword = GetKeyword(o);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
                return keyword;
            o = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(o);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

В главное окно напихал контролов с расставленным контекстным хелпом:

```
<Window x:Class="ContextHelp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContextHelp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        PreviewKeyDown="OnContextHelpKey">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Name="MainContent" local:Help.Keyword="Whole application">
            <Button Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Click="OnContextHelpRequest"
                    local:Help.Keyword="Context help button">?</Button>
            <Button Height="25" Width="75" local:Help.Keyword="Test button">
                Test button
            </Button>
            <TextBox Width="150">No context help here</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent" Name="ContextHelpCoverLayer"
              MouseLeftButtonDown="OnContextHelpClicked"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Реализация логики вместе с реакцией на Escape и F1 и запуском самого хелпа тут:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    static MainWindow()
    {
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Help,
                               new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(ExecuteHelp),
                               new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(CanExecuteHelp)));
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static void CanExecuteHelp(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameworkElement el = sender as FrameworkElement;
        if (el != null)
        {
            string keyword = Help.FindKeyword(el);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
                args.CanExecute = true;
        }
    }

    static void ExecuteHelp(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = args.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
        string keyword = Help.GetKeyword(parent);
        LaunchHelp(keyword);
    }

    static void LaunchHelp(string keyword)
    {
        if (keyword == null)
            return;
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            MessageBox.Show(keyword, "Context help", MessageBoxButton.OK));
    }

    bool showingHelp = false;
    void OnContextHelpRequest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextHelpCoverLayer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ContextHelpCoverLayer.Focus();
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Help;
        showingHelp = true;
    }

    void OnContextHelpClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
        CloseHelp();
        var result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MainContent, point);
        if (result == null)
            return;
        var clickedItem = result.VisualHit;
        var keyword = Help.FindKeyword(clickedItem);
        LaunchHelp(keyword);
    }

    void OnContextHelpKey(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (showingHelp && e.Key == Key.Escape)
            CloseHelp();
    }

    void CloseHelp()
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
        ContextHelpCoverLayer.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        showingHelp = false;
    }
}
```

По клику курсор меняется на знак вопроса, поверх всего UI показывается прозрачный лэйер, который ловит клики и передаёт их обработчику. Обработчик закрываете лэйер, определяет целевой контрол, и вычитывает из него навешенную контекстную информацию. Всё!

Результат:

[image: контекстная помощь]

Comment: спасибо! буду тыкаться по вашему пути)

Comment: @HellRiser: Добавил пример кода. Изучайте.

Comment: Покорнейше благодарю, добрый человек!!! )

Comment: @HellRiser: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что помогло.